# Bathtub draining slow

Tags: bathtub, drainage

My bathtub drains very slowly. Even when it's finished draining it still has water sitting at the top of the drain. Even trying to use Drano causes the Drano to back up into the bottom of the tub because if the water still in the drain. What can I do to get the water to go down a bit?

Comment: Was it always like that, or developed suddenly?

Comment: Like that after installing a new tub

Answer (score 2):

*(We should have a Canonical Post for drain cleaning, as for a few other things, but SE doesn't really have a good place for that.)*

There are a bunch of ways to clear drains. Unfortunately, the same solution doesn't work for everyone or even sometimes for the same drain at different times.

- Chemicals

Drano, but many others. Basically there are really strong chemicals (typically [lye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lye) but there are others) which can often do the job, as they generally work well on common bathtub problems (hair and soap). There are some others (enzymes, and some other things) which are touted as being effective for maintenance - i.e., use periodically to clean up the pipes - but that generally don't work as well, if at all, for a full clog.

Chemicals are nasty. But they often work, and they are incredibly easy to use - pour, wait, flush with water.

If they don't work...

- Pressure

There are gadgets that use CO2 cartridges to give a quick, moderate size, push of gas through the pipes. That sometimes works.

There are gadgets that use water pressure to put extra pressure on a clog. That sometimes works.

You can use a shop vac (in blowing mode, not sucking - usually a matter of moving the big hose to the other side) to put a lot of air pressure on a clog. That sometimes works.

All of the "pressure" options depend on:

- Blocking all other outputs (overflow, other pipes connected nearby, etc.) so that the pressure all goes to the one blocked pipe.
- The clog being close enough that the pressure will get to it without dissipating. This is particularly the case for something like CO2 cartridges because the pressure is from a one-shot item - if it is spread out over 50 feet of pipe it will have little effect.
- Snake

This is the gold standard. There are small manual snakes (e.g., 25'). There are some motorized versions and some of the manual ones are designed to attach to a drill as well. There are big motorized snakes, but those are more for larger pipes - e.g., the main drain accessed either through a basement floor drain or by removing a toilet. Snaking is, in my opinion, hard and messy work. But sometimes it is necessary.

The good news is that if you are only having problem with the bathtub and not with your bathroom sink or other bathrooms or kitchen then the problem is likely to be fairly close, often within 10' or so. So since chemicals didn't work, I would try a shop vac next if you have one and if that doesn't work or if you don't have one, get a 25' snake.

**Warning: Be extremely careful if you have any chemicals still sitting in the tub/drain.** Most of the time, I have found that a "fully clogged" drain is more like 98% clogged and if you let it sit for several hours then it drains enough that you can safely work on it with mechanical (snake or pressure) means.

Comment: Re: Pressure - there's always the good old-fashioned sink plunger [UK Store example](https://www.screwfix.com/p/rothenberger-drain-sink-unblocker-100mm/80690) for just a few bucks/quid. Cheap as chips, lasts a lifetime. Every home should have one ;) It works as a push/pull rather than just push & is remarkably effective.

Comment: Re the canonical idea - some Stacks have specific Meta questions for canonical lists. This is the Ask Different one - https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2418/where-is-the-list-of-canonical-questions-stored-for-ask-different It just needs someone with sufficient knowledge/rep to get it started, then mark it as Community Wiki & let it be filled by other contributors. Just perhaps keeing an eye on it periodically so it doesn't go astray.